# Java: Sorting Elements

Tags: java, sorting

I know we normally use [`java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[], Comparator)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29). The JavaDoc says it is a modified mergesort.

But I need a sorting algorithm that compares every object with every object. I will have a lot of elements of wich the order doesn't matter. But there are some elements that really need to come after a specific other element (not necessary consecutive). And I think (but don't know) that the mergesort is not enough...

Perhaps, what I want to achieve is not even called *sorting*?

Do I need to implement such a system my own, or does there exist something for this?

---

Example:

```
Obj1, Obj2, Obj3, Obj4
```

The order of following couples doesn't matter (which mean my Comparator should return 0):

```
Obj1, Obj2 (*)
Obj1, Obj3
Obj2, Obj3
Obj2, Obj4 (*)
Obj3, Obj4
```

But! It is really necessary that *Obj4* is followed by *Obj1*.

Because of the two (*) couples, this Mathematically means that Obj1 == Obj4.

Will it work using mergesort?

Thanks

Comment: Your custom sorting can and should be very well achieved implementing a Comparator.

Comment: Please could you clarify your requirements by posting a simple (but complete) example?

Comment: You should clarify a bit more how you want to "sort" your elements.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit about the use case here? I have the suspicion, that you are looking for “topological sorting“, but it is hard to tell by your description.

Comment: If aardvarkk's answer doesn't fit, you probably need to explain what you need more.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: From your example it seems that you can do away with the sort. See my updated answer.

Comment: I think your speculation above is likely correct: what you want is not sorting.  I say this because of the identity rule you define above:  (if Obj2 mustfollow Obj1 and Obj4 mustfollow Obj2, then Obj1==Obj4).  Whatever "mustfollow" means, it's nothing to do with sorting.

Comment: Do your objects have a convenient key - a unique field or method?

Comment: @Ed Staub: Yes, they have an ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your ideal ordering, one option is to add some sortable value like an integer that represents relationships between the data. For instance, if item A has to come before item B, then make sure its sorting value is less than item B's value. Then you can provide a custom comparator that only looks at the sort values and you can use a standard sorting algorithm.

Comment: An additional field may not be necessary - if the sort value is rapidly computable from values already present.

Comment: Yep, this is true! It would depend on how the objects worked and whether it took a long time to compute that value, etc. But good point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a set of DAGs (directed acyclic graphs).  I think you'll need to model this and then do a topological sort on each one.  One approach:

Wrap each element in a wrapper object that references the object and has a list for holding dependencies to other objects.  Put all these wrappers in a hashMap keyed by object id.

For all elements with no direct dependencies, emit the element, and remove it from the hashMap.  Repeat until hashmap is empty.

If dependency lists are often long, this will be inefficient.  It's intended for an average number of direct dependencies under 5 or so.  If performance is a problem because too many "Repeat until hashmap is empty" passes are being made, a bidirectional data structure for representing the dependency graphs should be used, or maybe, a list of the map entries that have only one dependency on this pass, and thus are strong candidates for the next pass.

Here's an untested sketch:

```
class Obj           { String id;    }

class ObjWrapper    {
    String id;
    Obj obj;
    String[] depends; // may be null, may have null entries

    public ObjWrapper(Obj obj, String[] depends) {
        this.id = obj.id;
        this.obj = obj;
        if ( depends != null )
            this.depends = Arrays.copyOf(depends, depends.length);
    }
}

// order the objects by dependency. 
ArrayList<Obj> orderObjs(Iterable<ObjWrapper> objs)
{
    ArrayList<Obj> output = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, ObjWrapper> objMap = new HashMap();
    for ( ObjWrapper obj : objs )  
        objMap.put(obj.id, obj);  
    while ( !objMap.isEmpty() ) {
        Iterator<ObjWrapper> iter = objMap.values().iterator();
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            ObjWrapper objWrapper = iter.next();
            if ( !hasDependencies(objWrapper, objMap) ) {
                output.add(objWrapper.obj);
                // must use iter to remove from hash, or bad things happen.
                iter.remove();  
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

boolean hasDependencies(ObjWrapper objWrapper, 
                        HashMap<String, ObjWrapper> objMap)
{
    if ( objWrapper.depends == null ) return false;
    for ( String depend : objWrapper.depends )   {
        if ( depend != null ) 
            if ( objMap.containsKey(depend) )
                return true;
            else
                depend = null;  // to speed up future passes
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find your requirements a little unclear. However, from what I gather you should be able to achieve this by providing an appropriate comparator.

**edit** Now that you've added an example, I don't think you even need a sort. Let's say elements X, Y and Z have to come after some element A. All you have to do is shift X, Y and Z to the end of your list. This can be done in `O(n)` time as opposed to the sort's `O(n logn)`.

Alternatively, you can move A to the start of your list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an order between the elements (i.e. you can say this one is smaller than this one), then the merge sort (as well as any sorting algo) will actually sort the collection.

Try to express formally (mathematically) the final ordering you need.

The fact that the order of two elements does not matter does not mean that your comparator must return 0. It must return 0 iif they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You have implement comparator (and pass it to standard mergesort), something like this:

```
int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
  if (o1 instanceOf NotMatter) {
     if (o2 instanceOf NotMatter) {
        return 0;
     }
     return -1;
  }
  if (o2 instanceOf NotMatter) {
     return 1;
  }

  // ok, now we have two important objects
  if (o1.better(o2) {
     return 1;
  }
  if (o2.better(o1) {
     return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```